# Is it possible to build an app with 4.4w (level 20) and use google apis?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have an app that requires google apis, but after updating everything, there is no build target for android level 20 (4.4W) that includes google apis.

[image]

is there a way to build an app targeting level 20 that requires google apis?

Comment: Not currently, I think. Which APIs are you using?

Comment: maps v1 - that's what i get for using deprecated apis

Comment: You cannot use them in the wear part module anyway. So you could build the mobile module targeting Google APIs and the wear module targeting 4.4W. Have you tried this?

Comment: @matiash i have not. how do you combine the two into one apk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't normally create an **Android Wear** application that uses Google Maps API v1. Instead, you would need two APKs:

- A *mobile* module (installed in the handheld, that uses whatever libraries you need).
- A *wear* module (installed on the Android Wear device).

This is actually *necessary*, because you *cannot* directly distribute Wear applications on the Play Store: they must be bundled inside a standard app (and is then pushed to the Wear device when installed in the handheld).

Android Studio makes this process much easier, since it can automatically do this bundling (you just create a new project, and mark checkboxes to create the Mobile and Wear modules).

If you need to do this manually (perhaps because you're using Eclipse instead) then you can follow the instructions at [Packaging Wearable Apps - Manually](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html#PackageManually). You basically have to:

- Include the wear apk in res/raw.
- Provide an xml file in res/xml with some metadata, and an additional tag in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: I think you can now with the google micro maps in the latest APK.  https://github.com/dheera/android-wearmaps